# Why am I receiving an empty array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to compare the individual numbers in the array that I am passing as one of the arguments of my function, to the other argument which is a single number.

I'd like to push the numbers that are not equivalent into a new empty array, then return that array but for some reason I am only receiving and empty array. it seems that the numbers are not getting pushed.

```
function removeChar(arr, num) {
  let newArray = [];
  for (number of arr) {
   
    if (!number === num) {
      newArray.push(number);
       console.log(newArray)
    }
  }
  console.log(newArray);
}

removeChar([2,5,4,3], 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!number === num) {
```

first negates `number` (to a boolean) and then compares it against `num` (which will always be `false`, since `num` is a number, not a boolean). It's just like

```
if ((!number) === num) {
```

You need

```
if (number !== num) {
```

Or, even better:

```js
const removeChar = (arr, num) => arr.filter(val => val !== num);
console.log(removeChar([2, 5, 4, 3], 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the array.filter method instead which returns whatever is true in the condition you’re setting.